# LaTeX Feature diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, overleaf, tikz-angles

I applied the following code to draw a feature diagram, however,
I do not want all child nodes to be concrete, as this code shows
In particular, I need to specify some of the child node to be abstract

How can I do that?
And also, how can I make disjunct branches (unfilled angle)  (e.t. as not all the child nodes are alternatives in my case)?

I took the code form [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335708/feature-diagram-in-latex)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,shadows.blur,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare count register=disjuncts from,
  disjuncts from'=0,
  declare count register=concrete from,
  concrete from'=2,
  concrete colour/.code={\colorlet{concretecol}{#1}},
  abstract colour/.code={\colorlet{abstractcol}{#1}},
  draw colour/.code={\colorlet{drawcol}{#1}},
  concrete colour=gray,
  abstract colour=white,
  draw colour=black,
  /tikz/mandatory/.style={circle, fill=drawcol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/optional/.style={circle, draw=drawcol, fill=white},
  /tikz/concrete/.style={fill=concretecol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/abstract/.style={fill=abstractcol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/or/.style={},
  mandatory/.style={edge label={node [mandatory] {}}},
  optional/.style={edge label={node [optional] {}}},
  or/.style={for first={disjunct}},
  disjunct/.style={
    tikz+={\path (.parent) coordinate (A) -- (!u.children) coordinate (B) -- (!ul.parent) coordinate (C) pic [fill=drawcol] {angle};}
  },
  disjunction tree/.style={
    where={isodd(n_children())}{
      for n={int((n_children()+1)/2)}{calign with current},
    }{
      calign=midpoint,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={
        filter/.wrap pgfmath arg={{level>=##1}{n_children()>1}}{(disjuncts_from)}
      }{
        or,
      },
      where={level()>=(concrete_from)}{
        concrete,
      }{
        abstract,
      },
      tikz+={
        [font=\sffamily]
        \node (l) [anchor=north west, xshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.north east) {Legend};
        \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \k (initially l)] in {mandatory/Mandatory,optional/Optional,or/Or,abstract/Abstract,concrete/Concrete}
        {
          \node (\i) [below=20pt of \k.north, anchor=north, text centered, \i, minimum width=5pt,] {};
          \node (\j) [right=15pt of \i.center -| mandatory.west, anchor=west] {\j};
        };
        \draw [drawcol] (or.south west) coordinate (A) -- (or.north) coordinate (B) -- (or.south east) coordinate (C) pic [fill=drawcol, angle radius=5pt] {angle};
        \foreach \i in {mandatory,optional} \draw [darkgray] (\i.north east) -- +(45:5pt);
        \node (c) [below=0pt of Concrete.south] {};
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [draw, fill=white, blur shadow, fit=(l) (Mandatory) (Optional) (Or) (Abstract) (Concrete) (c), rounded corners] {};}
      },
    },
    for tree={
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      l'+=10mm,
      blur shadow,
      rounded corners,
      text height=2ex,
      text depth=.5ex,
      font=\sffamily,
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}% addaswyd o gôd Salim Bou: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335782/
  disjunction tree,
  disjuncts from'=1,
  concrete from'=1,
  concrete colour=blue!85!cyan!40,
  abstract colour=blue!85!cyan!15,
  draw colour=darkgray,
  [Emergency Response System
    [User interface, mandatory]
    [Inform emergency,  mandatory
      [Inform Earthquake, abstract colour=blue!85!cyan!15]
      [Inform flood]
    ]
    [Display neighbourhood, mandatory
      [Map
        [Display danger zone]
        [Display safe zone]
        [Display path to safe zone]
      ]
      [Textual direction]
    ]
    [Shortcut calls, optional
      [Cops]
      [Ambulance]
      [Fireman]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, How can I add an angle filled with white color and also add it to legend and named as (Alternative) as in this diagram [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `forest`, so just take this as an attempt:

- To mark a child node as abstract, just add option `abstract` to that node, for example `[Display danger zone, abstract]`.

  Corresponding code changes: the block

  ```
  where={level()>=(concrete_from)}{
    concrete,
  }{
    abstract,
  },
  ```

  are moved from inside `before typesetting nodes={...}` to inside `for tree={...}`.
- Now the `or` angles are only drawn without filling by default. You can use `or={list of <start/end> pairs}` to specify the filled (sub)angles. For example `or={1/l}` means fill the (sub)angle from the 1st child node to the last, and `or={1/2, 4/5}` means fill the (sub)angles from 1st to 2nd, and 4th to 5th, respectively.

  Corresponding code changes: Definition of style `disjunct` is adjusted.

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,shadows.blur,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare count register=disjuncts from,
  disjuncts from'=1,
  declare count register=concrete from,
  concrete from'=1,
  concrete colour/.code={\colorlet{concretecol}{#1}},
  abstract colour/.code={\colorlet{abstractcol}{#1}},
  draw colour/.code={\colorlet{drawcol}{#1}},
  concrete colour=blue!85!cyan!40,
  abstract colour=blue!85!cyan!15,
  draw colour=darkgray,
  /tikz/mandatory/.style={circle, fill=drawcol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/optional/.style={circle, draw=drawcol, fill=white},
  /tikz/concrete/.style={fill=concretecol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/abstract/.style={fill=abstractcol, draw=drawcol},
  /tikz/or/.style={},
  mandatory/.style={edge label={node [mandatory] {}}},
  optional/.style={edge label={node [optional] {}}},
  or/.style={for first={disjunct={#1}}},
  disjunct/.style={
    tikz+={
      \path (.parent) coordinate (A) -- (!u.children) coordinate (B) -- (!ul.parent) coordinate (C) pic {angle};
      \foreach \i/\j in {#1} {
        \path (!u\i.parent) coordinate (A) -- (!u.children) coordinate (B) -- (!u\j.parent) coordinate (C) pic [fill=drawcol] {angle};
      }
    }
  },
  disjunction tree/.style={
    where={isodd(n_children())}{
      for n={int((n_children()+1)/2)}{calign with current},
    }{
      calign=midpoint,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={
        filter/.wrap pgfmath arg=
          {{level>=##1}{n_children()>1}}{(disjuncts_from)}
      }{
        or
      },
%      where={level()>=(concrete_from)}{
%        concrete,
%      }{
%        abstract,
%      },
      tikz+={
        [font=\sffamily]
        \node (l) [anchor=north west, xshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.north east) {Legend};
        \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \k (initially l)] in {mandatory/Mandatory,optional/Optional,or/Or,abstract/Abstract,concrete/Concrete}
        {
          \node (\i) [below=20pt of \k.north, anchor=north, text centered, \i, minimum width=5pt,] {};
          \node (\j) [right=15pt of \i.center -| mandatory.west, anchor=west] {\j};
        };
        \draw [drawcol] (or.south west) coordinate (A) -- (or.north) coordinate (B) -- (or.south east) coordinate (C) pic [fill=drawcol, angle radius=5pt] {angle};
        \foreach \i in {mandatory,optional} \draw [darkgray] (\i.north east) -- +(45:5pt);
        \node (c) [below=0pt of Concrete.south] {};
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [draw, fill=white, blur shadow, fit=(l) (Mandatory) (Optional) (Or) (Abstract) (Concrete) (c), rounded corners] {};}
      },
    },
    for tree={
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      l'+=10mm,
      blur shadow,
      rounded corners,
      text height=2ex,
      text depth=.5ex,
      font=\sffamily,
      where={level()>=concrete_from()}{
        concrete,
      }{
        abstract,
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}% addaswyd o gôd Salim Bou: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335782/
  disjunction tree,
  [Emergency Response System
    [User interface, mandatory]
    [Inform emergency, mandatory,for children={abstract}
      [Inform Earthquake]
      [Inform flood]
    ]
    [Display neighbourhood, mandatory,or={1/l} % 1 (the first) to ell (the last)
      [Map,or={2/3}
        [Display danger zone,abstract]
        [Display safe zone]
        [Display path to safe zone]
      ]
      [Textual direction]
    ]
    [Shortcut calls, optional,or={1/2,4/5}
      [Cops]
      [Ambulance]
      [Fireman,abstract]
      [Node]
      [Node]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me for my edit adding the image. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano That's always welcome, and thank you for adding it.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for your help 
How I can add an angle filled with white color and also add it to legend and named as (Alternative) as in this diagram [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281701630_Generating_Tests_for_Detecting_Faults_in_Feature_Models/figures?lo=1)

Comment: Are there any rules about where the abstract nodes will appear? Do they always appear at the beginning of the list of children nodes?